# How do I get the jmod file of a given JDK class and walk tree of jmod?

Tags: java, java-module, java-platform-module-system

Up to JDK8, I could use the following to iterate on rt.jar classes. Given a single class, I could  find all others like this :

```java
final URL location = clazz.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
final File file = new File(location.toURI());
try (JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(file)) {
    final Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jarFile.entries();
    while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
        final JarEntry jarEntry = entries.nextElement();
        // do something...
    }
}
```

After JDK8, using this `clazz.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()` isn't valid anymore:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.security.CodeSource.getLocation()" because the return value of "java.security.ProtectionDomain.getCodeSource()" is null
```

Is there good replacement for this ?
I'm thinking of doing a special case like this:

```java
if (clazz.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource() == null) {
  // find URL to the jmod ...
}
```

However a solution that will work in both cases would be preferable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s a wrong assumption in your question, as [classes are never loaded from a .jmod file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73066082/2711488).

You can get the location of a module like

```java
Module m = clazz.getModule();
System.out.println(m.getLayer().configuration()
    .findModule(m.getName()).flatMap(rm -> rm.reference().location())
    .orElse(null));
```

which doesn’t work for the “unnamed module”, read classes loaded through the classpath, so you would have to resort to `.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()` if `m.isNamed()` is `false`.

However, for the built-in modules, the URI will always be `jrt:/module-name`, so to iterate over the platform classes, you don’t need this at all.

For example, this code snippet lists all classes in the `java.lang` package:

```java
try(var list = Files.list(Paths.get(URI.create("jrt:/java.base/java/lang")))) {
         list.map(p -> p.getFileName().toString())
             .filter(s -> s.endsWith(".class"))
             .map(s -> "java.lang." + s.substring(0, s.length() - 6))
             .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

and to get the class file bytes for `java.lang.Object`, you can simply use

```java
byte[] objectClassFile = Files.readAllBytes(
    Paths.get(URI.create("jrt:/java.base/java/lang/Object.class")));
```